# $(5^{2x}-1)(5^x)=1/5^x$ solve

Tags: calculus, logarithms, exponentiation

I have the problem $(5^{2x}-1)(5^x) = 1/5^x$.

I have already simplified it to $5^{3x}-1=1/5^x$ My question is when I do $\log$ base $5$ to the left side of the equation to get $3x-1$ by itself so that I can figure out $x$, what do I get when I do $\log$ base $5$ to the other side of the equation? Does the $5$ cancel out? What happened to the exponent etc.

[image: math problem]!

Number 2 is the problem i am talking about in the image above

all these are confusing me, all I want to know is when I do log base 5 to one over 5^x (1/5^x), what happens :(

Comment: First you have to write the equation in a way that is legible.  Two people have guessed, one in the edit, one in an answer.  They do not agree-is one right?  I suspect not.  Parentheses and formatting will help a lot.

Answer (score 6):

Hint: let $y = 5^x$. then you have: $y^3 - y = 1/y$. You can take it from here.

Answer (score 0):

Let $a=5^x$. Then, $a^3-a=\dfrac{1}{a}$, so
$$a^4-a^2-1=0$$
The solutions are
$$a=\pm  1.2720196495139988,\pm0.7861513777573095i$$
Take the $\log$ base $5$ to get (note - only the $\log$s of the positive solutions are taken)
$$x= 0.14949685892,(-1.2030295627\times10^{-1})+\dfrac{i\pi}{2}$$
As @RecklessReckoner has said, we will consider only the real values to get
$$\boxed{x= 0.14949685892\mbox{, and as said in the comments, }\log_5\left(\sqrt{\dfrac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}}\right)}$$

Comment: Since this is for a calculus class, I think the imaginary values for $ \ a \ $ can be discarded.

Comment: @RecklessReckoner Yes, I believe so.

Comment: For reference: the closed form of the (unique) positive solution is 
$$
a = \sqrt{\frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}}
$$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Thanks. May I have your permission to add that into the answer?

Comment: I'm guessing that the course hasn't talked about what to do with logarithms of imaginary numbres.  @Omnomnomnom  Yes, the Golden Ratio surfaces yet again!

Comment: @SanathDevalapurkar of course! If you want to derive it, note that $$a^4 - a^2 - 1 = (a^2)^2 - (a^2) - 1$$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Thanks!

Comment: @SanathDevalapurkar you should have
$$
x = \log_5\left(\sqrt{\frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}} \right)
$$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom My mistake - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your simplification of the lefthand side is incorrect. Note that:
$$(5^{2x}-1)(5^x)\ne 5^{3x-1}$$
And instead:
$$(5^{2x}-1)(5^x)=(5^{2x}\cdot 5^x)-(1\cdot5^x)=5^{2x+x}-5^x=5^{3x}-5^x$$
This is by: $$(a-b)c=ac-bc$$

Now you'll have 
$$5^{3x}-5^x=\frac{1}{5^x}$$
To solve, let $y=5^x$ as was suggested in E-theory's answer, and you'll get:
$$y^3-y=\frac{1}{y}$$
Also note that:$$5^{3x}=\left(5^x\right)^3$$